# Batch adds additional \ in cp path

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

I wrote a batch script, which is branching my project for `svn` and want to create docs with `sphinx` which I then copy into the branched path.

The part where I do this is:

```
ECHO ##### Creating Docs Branch %VERSION%

cd %~dp0\trunk\Python\MyPackage\docs
call make html
cp -r _build\html %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage

svn add %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage
svn commit %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage -m "Added Docs Branch %VERSION%"
```

This fails with `cp: cannot mkdir "D:/00_Workspace/MyProject/MyPackage//branches/1.1.0/Python/docs/MyPackage": Path could not be found`

Apparently there is a second `/` added between `MyPackage` and `branches`
Why does this happen?

Here is the full version of the `batch`

```
@echo off
set "VERSION=%1"
set "COMMON_VERSION=%2"

if "%VERSION%"=="" set /p VERSION=Enter the version number you want to create the branch for?: 
if "%COMMON_VERSION%"=="" set /p COMMON_VERSION=Enter the version number of the common python toolchain you want to use?: 

set PACKAGE_NAME=%~dp0

ECHO ##### Updating SVN Repository

svn update

ECHO ##### Creating requirements.txt
cd trunk
call python create_requirements_txt.py %VERSION% %COMMON_VERSION%
svn add requirements.txt
svn commit requirements.txt -m "Updated requirements.txt to version %VERSION%"
cd %~dp0

ECHO ##### Creating Branch for version %VERSION%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('svn info ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"Relative URL"') do set URL=%%i
set "URL=%URL:*: =%"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('svn info ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"Repository Root"') do set ROOT=%%i
set "ROOT=%ROOT:*: =%"

set "DEST_URL=%ROOT%%URL:*\trunk=%/branches/%VERSION%"
set "SRC_URL=%ROOT%%URL%/trunk"

ECHO ##### Package: %PACKAGE_NAME%
ECHO ##### Source: %SRC_URL%
ECHO ##### Destination: %DEST_URL%

call svn copy %SRC_URL% %DEST_URL% -m "Branch %PACKAGE_NAME% Version %VERSION%"

ECHO ##### Succesfully created branch %VERSION%
call svn update

ECHO ##### Creating Docs Branch %VERSION%

cd %~dp0\trunk\Python\MyPackage\docs
call make html
cp -r _build\html %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage

svn add %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage
svn commit %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage -m "Added Docs Branch %VERSION%"
pause
exit /b 0

:SVN_ERROR
ECHO ##### SVN Error: Either Source Repo (%SRC_URL%) does not exist or the Tag (%DEST_URL%) already exists!
pause
exit /b 1
```

Comment: `%~dp0` contains drive letter plus path from where script is run ended with backslash. change `svn add %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage` with `svn add %~dp0branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage` and all similar paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @elzooilogico said

> `%~dp0` contains drive letter plus path from where script is run ended with backslash. change `svn add %~dp0\branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage` with `svn add %~dp0branches\%VERSION%\Python\docs\MyPackage` and all similar paths.

that should work.

Comment: I typically assign `%~dp0` to a local environment variable and strip off the trailing backslash. It's easier for me to read `%SCRIPT_DIR%\branches\...`.